# Getting elements from different html files using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get an HTML element from 2 different html files. The problem is I only get one of them.

`var message1 = document.getElementById("message1")` works.

But when I try to do the same for the element in the other html page:

`var message2 = document.getElementById("message2")` it returns null

I have a main html file (`index.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id = "message1">I hate the post office</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I also have another html file (`page2.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id = "message2">Random sentence</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And finally I have a javascript file (`script.js`):

```
//Gets message1 from index.html (works)
var message1 = document.getElementById("message1")
//logs message1 from index.html (works)
console.log(message1)

//gets message2 from page2.html (doesn't work)
var message2 = document.getElementById("message2")
//logs message2 from page2.html (logs null)
console.log(message2)
```

How do I get the elements of id `message` and `message2` in `script.js`?

Comment: What do you mean by "secondary html file"? How is the secondary file included in the page?

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant another html file (edited). All 3 files listed are in one folder

Comment: Right, but is there anything telling the browser to download the second file and include it in the page in some way?

Comment: It's hosted on repl.it so I don't think I need to tell the browser to download the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try this another way using `iframe`. Add in `index.html` page

```
<p id="message">I hate the post office</p>
<iframe src="page2.html" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I can't get both the elements in the same javascript file?

Comment: Try this @Dregg. This is the short solution.

Comment: I tried this but message2 still returns null. message1 still works.

Do I need to change the javascript file after adding this iframe?

Comment: Nvm I tried opening it in a new tab and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious though, what's the long solution?